# Error: Failed building the interaction model.

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm developing a skill, I have an interaction model and 3 custom slot types. When I had toy values for the slot types everything seems to work but when I paste the values for the custom slot types and hit save, first I get a spinning wheel saying updating interaction model, then another one saying `Please wait while model is being built...` after a couple minutes I get a red error message that says: `Error: Failed building the interaction model.`

I pasted about 100 utterances and about 30, 300 and 30,000 values in my custom slot types. According to the documentation: `A skill can have a total of 50,000 custom slot values, totaled across all custom slots used in the interaction model.` https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interaction-model-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interaction model builder has been known to break. Some times you have to wait a day or two for it to reset. Complaining on the developer forum or submitting a "Contact Us" request can sometimes get action.

You don't say which of your 30, 300, or 30,000 value test work and which don't. A point to bear in mind, though, is that after a couple hundred, the quality of recognition only improves slightly. The list of words you give for a custom slot is "advice". It isn't a hard-and-fast list. Alexa may return to you words not on your list. The more words you have, the wider and more arbitrary the input it will return. So, although you can submit 50,000 words, it is seldom profitable to do so.

Comment: That is a very interesting insight. I was under the assumption I would always get only words from my list. Once I pasted the 30,000 values, no matter what I changed in the other slot types it wouldn't work.

Comment: It's easy to forget that Alexa does audio processing, not text processing. Most people think it goes speech to text, then text to intent+slots, and they keep asking for things like regular expression matching. To produce a higher quality, it goes straight from speech to intent+slots. This produces higher accuracy, at the expense of a more restricted vocabulary. 

If you really want to restrict it to values in your list, you have to do the fuzzy match step yourself. DoubleMetaphone is a commonly available algorithm that people have used successfully for that. Depends on your content, though.

Comment: Thanks! I already though about something like that but I was trying to avoid it. By the way, my 300 list is world countries and states and the 30,000 world city names. Because of the variety of different pronunciations I was hoping ASK would already try to map to something on the list for me.

Comment: StarLanes uses "small English towns" for it's locations. I have a list of 470. That gets it close enough. But I still have to use phonetic matching to really get what people mean.